# Query on a document name OR a field name?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a parameter named `parm` which can be a document name, **OR** a field name in a document.
I would like to check in a single query *both cases*.

```
CollectionA
  docA
  docB
  docC
```

and inside a document

```
 docA
   brand
      nick
```

So currently I can check for a document with a certain `nick`, with :

```
  db.collection("CollectionA").where("brand.nick", "==", parm)
```

Given that `parm` can now also be a **document name** (docB), I would like to add an `OR` to this query, to also check first if there is a document with that name in `parm`, if so return that document, ***otherwise***, check for a doc with `brand.nick` if exist.

Comment: @doug read that already, my question is a little bit different, don't read only the title. I am asking how to first check a document name, and then a query, in one shot.

Comment: You're describing essentially the same situation as the duplicate.  It requires two queries.  Firestore doesn't offer a logical OR across fields (the ID of the document is essentially a field with a special meaning).

Comment: ok thank you! will change the structure.